Minimum size of a hot spring or other water feature to cause lake effect snow?
The lake effect occurs when cold air passes over a relatively warmer body of water, saturating it with moisture that immediately precipitates en masse, creating a large amount of snow downwind.
This normally occurs only with relatively large bodies of water like the North American Great Lakes. But with a hot spring, the water is going to be a lot warmer, and more moist air will therefore be released. Obviously hot springs tend to be way smaller than, say, lake Erie, but I started to wonder how large they would have to be before anything resembling lake effect snow would start to happen. It's an absolutely unimportant detail at a worldwide scale, of course, but I think it would be fun to have, say, a valley-sized microclimate fueled by this boosted lake effect.
It could be from a single geologically heated lake, or a number of active hot springs, but my end question is what kind, size, and number of hot spring features would be required to noticeably create lake effect snow at a small scale during winter?
I'm also completely fine with this being relatively unfeasible, as it's a rather out there idea to begin with. Again, the area affected doesn't have to span more than something like a small valley but it can be larger if the effect is unlikely to be localized if it exists. Assume a small-to-medium sized river in terms of maximum available water input. Thanks!

define localized.

@L.Dutch That was remarkably fast! Localized in this case just refers to the fact that I'm looking for a small scale change in climate that's likely to be geographically isolated. But it's not actually that important to the question, and if it's really a choice between "no snow" and "larger scale impact" I would prefer the latter. But if this wording is too vague or misleading I can find a way to replace it.

if you don't define localized it won't be possible to give the minimum size of the water body. Is localized within 1/100/1000 meters from it?

I would consider something that small to be insignificant enough not to even affect the climate, a single "normal" sized hot spring probably doesn't create enough moisture to do anything meaningful. I think I provided a "valley-sized" example in the original text but have since edited it to add clarity based off of that example. If absolutely needed I can make up a geographic area but what I'm really trying to figure out is if hot springs can reasonably cause lake effect snow to begin with. I asked instead for scale specifically because geothermal conditions could easily vary planet to planet.

VTC:Needs More Details. A pan of boiling water will cause the "lake effect" if only by leading to a handful of flakes. We have the "lake effect" where I live, but the effect is measured regionally across a thousand square miles or more. So, as much as you don't want to limit yourself, without knowing the size and nature of the region in question, the question is meaningless.

My essential purpose is to determine if lake effect snow (arbitrarily, 6 or more inches of added snow) could occur due to geothermally heated springs and lakes. I worded the question differently because I didn't want people to say no simply based on earthlike geothermal conditions.
My reason for not giving XYZ parameters in which the effect would occur is that I'm asking what XYZ parameters would lead to this effect; how, not if, it's possible. I'm interested in general possibility rather than situational possibility, so the only constant is that the effect comes from hot springs.

Would you recommend that I reword or close the question?

What I recommend is carefully reading the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask]. Stack Exchange is a place where you can find help solving specific problems, not gaining generalized knowledge. Asking vague and poorly defined questions is literally the antithesis of what SE is about. And as I said, a boiling pot creates a lake effect, just in an area so small it's useless. I also recommend researching lake effect snow. By definition, if you want 1m of snow over a 1,000 m^2 area you need to evaporate +/- 75 Kl of water. ... (*Continued*)

... The hot springs only lowers the temperature of the effect and/or speeds the process of evaporation, but you can't change the amount of evaporation needed to cover an area. Physics.

Maybe a relation can be formulated to relate thermal vent area to cubic Meter snow for typical conditions. Maybe the question itself should be understood to ask for the typical scaling here? I think this is a very interesting question, don't close

You could make the size of the spring needed smaller, by throwing up water into the air. Maybe by geyser, or by having the hot spring water flow down a waterfall, creating mist. Kinda like a natural snow cannon.

To outline for an answer. Should be doable in a contrived environment at small scale. Bring air in over a warm area eg a dry solarheated valley. Then have nice humidiying waterfalls, leading into a termal valley that has thermal falls and maybe a wind that lifts up spray curtains to fuirther help humidity. THEN drop warm saturated air into a valley towards away from sun side of a mountain with steep snow slopes above (or just steep cool slopes) providing cooling. May take some constructing but seems doable. Quite small scale indeed sounds doable

This is exactly what happens with geysers in Iceland or Yellowstone in winter.
The boiling hot water is throw in the air, cools down and freezes very quickly and then falls as snow (or black ice or sleet) to the ground nearby.
The effect is quite local, several meters to maybe a couple of 100 meters, depending on size of the geyser and the prevailing wind conditions.
So you don't really need a lake at all.

is that still "lake effect" though? As I read it, the question was specifically about that one, not about boiling water / steam getting thrown up and snowing back down

So,  a hot spring generates - unless situated in a protective valley -a  chimney/stack effect. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_effect
And a chimney drags in cold air, that condenses out wet-hot air (relative to the surroundings) into snow.. so any snow that happens, happens in what looks like a treestem - and will partially fall out around the hot spring dragged in by the current. Depending turbulence snow might be dragged in, to melt and come down as a sleet rain on the hotspring. In theory, depending on the prevailing wind streams and the coalescing of steam, you could even form hail balls.
Which leads to the question- are large iceballs, falling on a guys head in a hot spring, covering the surface  and bottom with cold pools in the hotsoup - turning you into a soup with crouton- or a cocktail?

This is really interesting! Thanks! Now I'm imagining some kind of geothermally heated waterfall shedding snow as it falls. Ethereal.
Anyways, this helps out a lot, I think; the amount of moisture added at a point is going to be distributed very locally because the colder air temperature still has that maximum tolerance. Anything at a large scale would have to actually warm up the region a bit to not lose all its moisture. Neat! I might make a self-answer out of this later.

Geysers Won't Cut It

Since you're asking about lake effect snow (there's also lake effect rain), as opposed to just ordinary winter weather, the geography is what is going to rule the day. A review of the Wikipedia article reveals one really key factor that rules out geysers, hotsprings, tea pots and the like: fetch. Fetch is the distance the wind travels over open water. More fetch = more water being absorbed into the air = lake effect snow.

Part of this key is "open water". Ice won't cut it, because there's not a lot of evaporation over it. The Great Lakes are a quintessential lake effect snow region because they, as a rule, don't freeze over. In contrast, another lake that causes such snowfall is Baikal in Russia; but because it does (eventually) freeze over, it's production of lake effect snow is reduced to early season snowfall.

Similar to the Great Lakes, lake effect snow occurs around the Great Salk Lake, the Caspian Sea, the Black Sea and the Baltic. Of all of these, GSL is probably about the smallest body water that easily supports lake effect snow. It's 75 mile length is just over the approximate minimum fetch length of 60 miles.

In contrast: a geyser can't produce lake effect snow because it doesn't meet the minimum criteria. It's literally just throwing liquid water into sufficiently cold air that it freezes. The resulting snow and ice fall is a different phenomenon.
